# log4j2 configure jdbc apender using properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Im new to log4j2 and trying to convert following log4j2.xml configuration into akey value pairs in log4j2.properties for couple of days now

```
   <Jdbc name="databaseAppender" tableName="APPLOGS">
        <DataSource jndiName="com.a.b.c"/>
        <Column name="ENTRY_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />
        <Column name="LOGLEVEL" pattern="%level" />
        <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" />
        <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" />
        <Column name="EXCEPTION" pattern="%throwable " />
    </Jdbc>
```

Im using `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` as my log4j2 and `spring-boot-starter-parent` version is `2.0.0.RELEASE`.also note that I tried the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942539/log4j2-how-to-convert-xml-configuration-to-properties-format-for-jdbc-appende) question's answer already and getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No name attribute provided for Appender dbAppender
```

highly appreciate if anyone can give a solution on this matter.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (log4j2.properties):

```
name=PropertiesConfig
status = error
dest = out

appender.db.type = JDBC
appender.db.name = org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
appender.db.connectionSource.type= DriverManager
appender.db.connectionSource.connectionString = <jdbc_db_url>
appender.db.connectionSource.username = <user>
appender.db.connectionSource.password = <password>
appender.db.connectionSource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
appender.db.tableName = logs

appender.db.columnConfigs[0].type = Column
appender.db.columnConfigs[0].name = userid
appender.db.columnConfigs[0].pattern =%X{username}
appender.db.columnConfigs[0].isUnicode =false

appender.db.columnConfigs[1].type = Column
appender.db.columnConfigs[1].name = message
appender.db.columnConfigs[1].pattern =%msg
appender.db.columnConfigs[1].isUnicode =false

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = database
rootLogger.appenderRef.database.ref = DB
```

application.properties:

```
# LOGGING
logging.level.org.springframework.web=${LOG_LEVEL_SPRING:info}
logging.level.org.hibernate=${LOG_LEVEL_SPRING:info}
logging.level.web=${LOG_LEVEL_SPRING:info}
logging.config=classpath:log4j2.properties
```

See more options here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender